# c# Dictionary to Datatable

Tags: dictionary, datatable

I have this dictionary:

```
KEY                   VALUE
08/10/2013, 00:00:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:01:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:02:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:03:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:04:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:05:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
08/10/2013, 00:06:00, a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
```

Where the date and time are my key, while 'a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h, i' are my values​​.

I would like to put the dictionary above in a `DataTable`.

How should I do this?
Use two `foreach` loops?

```
private static void DictonaryTodataTable (DataTable dtResult, Dictionary <DateTime, CommaSeparatedList> CSVData)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair item in <DateTime, CommaSeparatedList> CSVData)
    {
        DtResult.NewRow DataRow dr = ();
        
        [ CODE ]
        dtResult.Rows.Add (dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have looks OK - what is stopping it from working?

Comment: How do I insert the datatable in the dictionary?

I would like to have:

Timestamp -           Column 1 - Column 2 - Column 3 - Col...
08/10/2013, 00:00:00, a          b          c          d

Etc. ..

How do inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

A DataRow can hold either indexed or hashed values for columns. You can use either dr[0], dr[1]... or dr["columnA"], dr["columnB"]

Assuming CommaSeparatedList can iterate strings, you can replace [CODE] with this, although you may need a cast or something to handle fetching strings from the comma separated list.

```
int count = 0;
dr[count++] = item.Key; // You could cast this to a string and/or format it here...
foreach(string column in item.Value){ dr[count++]=column; }
```

Comment: Great, but how do I make the casting only the first element?
It must be a timestamp.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to.. it was just a suggestion, it all depends on your needs. You can assign the column as a DateTime object. The DataRow ItemArray takes an object[] so you can pass whatever you want. You can assign the entire array to the row or one column at a time. It's all in the docs...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataRow.aspx

Comment: Then, I looked at the documentation, my dictionary has a header that I would like to remove from the current dictionary but use it at a later time.

How can I do?

Thank you.